# AutoLayout: position of subview proportional to parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

**Let's supose** I have a UIImageView at y=10 while the screen is height:100.

What constraints do I have to set if I want the image to be always for example at y:10% of the parent? 
Parent height:100  -  UIImage y:10
Parent height:200  -  UIImage y:20
Parent height:320  -  UIImage y:32

Is there a way to do this without coding? (only constraints in Interface Builder)? Hint: before autolayout this was really easy.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Hint 2:   `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.1 constant:0.0];`

Comment: Hint: Before autolayout this was a mess when working with rotation/other screen sizes!

Comment: Damn I'm wrong! Ignore ME!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in interface builder using spacer views.

1. Put a hidden `UIView` in your parent view with 0 top spacing to it's superview.
2. Make the hidden `UIView` have equal height to the parent view with a multiplier of 0.1 so it is always 10% of the parent view's height.
3. Make your `UIImageView` have 0 top spacing to the hidden `UIView`.

This should make your `UIImageView` y position always 1/10th of the height of the parent view.

Comment: This works but it seems a bit tricky. Isn't there a more standard way? Thanks

Comment: @jobima, it seems to be odd but it is the way it works now...even Apple use similar trick in their guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8